# .net framework 4.0.30319 config file parse error

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I was trying to install sqlite for component one library and as per one tutorial I made a small change in 2 config files

1. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
2. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

change made to both files was the same just added 1 line entry and after that I have been getting this error on multiple programs, including skype, skype starts succesfully itelf but as it seems one of its services fails to start. I searched but didnt find any installer so I can repair this specific version of .net framework. any help would be appreciated thanks. Another thing to note is that I undid those changes and now both config files are back in their default condition but I am still getting this error.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing corrupted config files with the default ones. see solution one at : https://appuals.com/net-parsing-error-0xc00ce556/